# Excel Formula Writing

Tags: excel-formula

Please help as I am stuck in writing a formula.

I am working on a excel data which has following values in the columns. I want to write a IF formula which allows to compare the Product Name with its Items and their Status.

- If the Status of any of the Product # for that Product Name is Outstanding and Received, the output should be "PARTIAL INFO".
- If the Status of the Product # for that Product Name are all RECEIVED the output should be "FULL INFO".
- If the Status of the Product # for that Product Name are all OUTSTANDING the output should be "NO INFO RCVD".

Product

```
Name    Product #    Status         DESIRED OUTPUT

Alpha   item # 1    outstanding PARTIAL INFO
    item # 2    received    
    item # 3    received    
    item # 4    Outstanding 

Bravo   item # 4    Received    FULL INFO
    item # 5    Received    
    item # 6    Received    

Charlie item # 7    Outstanding NO INFO RCVD
    item # 8    Outstanding 
    item # 9    Outstanding 
    item # 11   Outstanding
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a second Name and Status column and sorting status Z-A within each product name. Could also add a blank row between Product names to keep it cleaner as well.

From there, you could try a nested =IF(AND(E3="outstanding",G3="outstanding"),"No Info Recvd",IF(AND(E3="Received",G3="Received"),"Full Info",IF(AND(E3="outstanding",G3="Received"),"Partial info","")))

This depends on the original status column already being sorted in A-Z order and that there is only Received and Outstanding in the status column.